What is this kanji? Image attatched
I found this kanji on what I believe is an old map. I don't recognize it and have been trying to look it up, but it does not show up when I search using radicals. What is this kanji?


We don't do transcriptions here. But this is clearly the traditional form of 図 — 圖, or rather a slight scribal variant of it, with the same meaning.

In case it's useful, a quick addendum: This variant form of traditional 圖, modern 図 is also the second character in the term 地図 meaning "map" (literally 地 "earth, land" + 図 "diagram, figure").

That should be the kanji 図, whose proper traditional form is 圖. The one you have, though, is just another variant form (異体字) of the same character, aka characters with the exact same sound and meaning, just written differently. Below you can see a screen shot of the Dictionary of Variant Characters (from Taiwan's ministry of education), which, in addition to the variant of 圖, provides a LOT more other variants of 圖 used historically.

